# Ruby Is it possible to create hash in array with space character?

Tags: ruby, hash, stdin

With STDIN, I want to create hash in array only by a space character.
My ideal is

```
$ Bob 90          # => [{"Bob" => 90}]
```

But my code in ruby file is

```
array = []
name = gets.chomp
score = gets.to_i
array.push({name => score})
```

then

```
$Bob
$90          # => [{"Bob"=> 90}]
```

Thank you for your consideration in advance.

Comment: My code works successfully by using `scanf` method!

Answer (score 1):

`[]` is an array, not a hash. And therefore, your example returns an array that contains one hash:

```
hash #=> [{"Bob" => 90}]
```

You probably want to create an empty hash (`{}`) and add entries to that hash:

```
hash = {}
name = gets.chomp
score = gets.to_i
hash[name] = score

hash #=> {"Bob" => 90}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm sorry that my explanation and codes weren't right. I edited some of the parts since you left me a great answer.  Is it possible to create hash in array in one line with stdin?